# How to make qiskit jupyter plot and draw properly

Tags: qiskit, programming

The problem:
You try to plot or draw more than once within a cell, or you try to plot or draw within a code block,but nothing comes out and you're going nuts... :)

Comment: Could you please add more details, for example code?

Comment: did you mean this as a self-answered post to share your knowledge of how to achieve this particular task? If so, that is generally on-topic and well-accepted, but it needs to be framed properly. In particular, could you'd need to better clarify the scope of the question and the exact problem that is being solved

Answer (score 1):

The solution:

Just wrap it with a `display()` function, example:

```
display(array_to_latex([0, 1]))

display(plot_histogram({'111' : 342}))
```

Now they will work like magic any time you call them. Yes, more than once in a cell. Yes, inside a function or a block too.